# sum column = value IF another cell contains text but only if a different cell is NULL

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to calculate the sum of cells `J10:M76` if `B10:E76` = a text value, but if cells `R10:R76` are not null (contain a value) I do NOT want to include the value that is in `J10:M76`.

I know this is a little complicated and this is what I am current doing to resolve it, but there must be a better way.

`=SUM(SUMIF($B$10:$E$76,{"City of Tampa"},$J$10:$M$76))-J13`

Comment: emmm... For example, B11 and E20 contain text you need, do you mean add value in J11 and M20, then if any values in column R I need to minus them. If my understanding correct?

Comment: You need an **Array Formula CSE**,`{=IF($R$10:$R$76="",SUMIF($B$10:$E$76,"City Of Tempa",$J$10:$M$76),"")}`

Comment: Some things in your question aren't quite clear.  1. What do you mean by B10:E76="text"?  Do all four columns in the row need to equal the text?  Any one column?  Having that same type of text in multiple columns isn't a typical way to construct data, so what's there and the requirement aren't clear.  2. Is each row another data record, so the rules apply by row (so you want to include all row values in columns J:M in the grand total as long as the criteria are met for the row)?  (cont'd)

Comment: 3. When you refer to null in col R, you just mean that the cell is empty?  So basically there are two conditions the row must meet: something you will clarify in B:E="text value", and R is not empty?  4. Will the target text only ever be "City of Tampa", so you want that hard coded in the formula, or might that vary, in which case it would make sense to enter that text in a cell somewhere and then reference that cell in the formula so the value can be easily changed?  (cont'd)

Comment: 5. What is the -J13?  That's within your data range, so is that an example of a non-qualifying value that you manually identified and hard-coded it's subtraction, assuming that would offset its inclusion?  If so, why only J and not J:M?  6. Complex requirements like this are always better to post with some sample data that covers the range of conditions you might encounter, what the result should be for that example, and why.  Otherwise, people will spend a lot of time trying to answer based on a misinterpretation of the requirements.

Comment: Also your multiple negatives in describing R are confusing.  Do you want to include the data if R has a value or R is blank?

Comment: Maybe I need to explain a little better.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use an array formula, this has a standard approach.

My take is that you wish to have the answer in a single cell so there should be no particular reason to avoid an array formula. (A common reason for multi-cell array formulas is the difficulty involved in changing the formula, and related issues. A block taken up by an array formula can act a lot like a block of cells merged into one.)

(This is only long so I can spell out the steps enough so you don't get maddened by a teensy detail I should have shown.)

If so, here is the concept:

Not only will the end formula be an array formula itself, entered using Control-Shift-Enter ("CSE"), but you form its parts into arrays.

One array will contain the values you (possibly) wish to sum (B10:M76 in this case). A second array will be the range with the desired text and the third array will be the range being tested for a null/blank/empty condition.

The first array's purpose is to put the values to add into play. The second and thirdd arrays' purposes are identical:  to perform the tests needed and return a logical calue for each test. Logical value? You will make them return TRUE or FALSE, depending upon the tests succeeding or failing.

Excel will treat those logical values as 1's and 0's if you conduct a math operation upon them. So the happy text column might produce {TRUE;FALSE;TRUE;TRUE;FALSE;...etc.} which will act as {1;0;1;1;0;... etc.} if you conduct a math operation on the result. Often you will do that to a single array by multiplying it by 1. Here you need a slighlty more involved path to solution and instead of bringing in a "*1", you will simply use the other two arrays. The third array is similar with you testing the cells for the null/blank/empty condition and getting the same kind of array of TRUE and FALSE.

So, first array places the range of summing values into an array, and the second and third arrays are the TRUE and FALSE results of the two tests you require. If either test fails, you will be multiplying the other test result by 0 resulting in 0 to multiply the summing value that matches by. So if either test fails, that row's summing value will be multiplied by 0 and result in a 0 to be added by the SUM() function you will wrap this all in. If both tests succeed, that row's summing value will be multiplied by 1 and end up in the final array Excel presents to the SUM() function.

That way SUM() adds nothing for the rows that fail one way or the other so only the values whose tests succeed will seem to be in the result.

Which is what you want.

In this case, you need to write the first test so that it produces a TRUE if it succeeds. Something like:

```
(B1:B6="City of Tampa")
```

and the second test needs to be written so it produces a 1 if the test fails, so to speak so write it as a "to not match" kind, or write it in a "positive" way but wrap that in a NOT() function:

```
(C1:C6<>"")
(NOT(C1:C6=""))
```

(Whichever approach makes best sense to you and will bestallow you to work on your spreadsheet in the future. Everyone is different here, and supervisor's sometimes express demands so they can audit it and be comfortable that it gives valid answers.)

Your first array is fairly simple, just the range of values you might sum all by itself:

```
A1:A6
```

(You have to enclose the test portions (second and third arrays) in parentheses, but do not need to do so for the first array. But can if you like.)

Then put them all together and wrap them with the SUM() function:

```
{=SUM( A1:A6 * (B1:B6="City of Tampa") * (C1:C6<>"") )}
```

(Pressing "CSE" will add the {} that wrap the above, of course.)

You can use this approach not only with lots of variations on the summing things front, but with a variety of other functions. In fact, a few do not even require the whole final formula to be entered with "CSE":  it can be a totally normal formula even though it uses arrays in its interim work. So if you follow the above, you can apply this approach to a lot of problems you will run into.

I did not recreate your problem exactly (hence my simple ranges in the examples) but often a multi-column-and-row range to operate upon requires a bit of extra work. A multi-row OR multi-column range is still a single row array, like a single line matrix. making it rows AND columns gives Excel (as it takes it) arrays with multiple rows, like, say, a 3x4 matrix. If you get errors, you must "unwind" that and force Excel to consider the ranges in question as single row arrays. For instance, use Named Ranges to pull together single columns (or rows if that's easier to write) into a single range. There are some other tricks too. One is to write the formula to do one set of calculations for a column in the range, and add that to a second set of calculations for the second column, etc. Not more complex, just several sets of the same thing shifted over for each set of columns. But usually you can cobble it together without too much trouble, just some elbow grease.

Lastly, I mentioned that some formulas use the arrays but do not need to be CSE entered formulas themselves. However, strangely often, until you get why each time whereupon it becomes truly understandable, like a Homer "Doh!" moment, doing so may give a different result than the exact same thing CSE entered. If so, the CSE entered version will always be the correct one, though you need to verify it each and every time.